# Removing part of a string C#

Tags: c#, string, split, tokenize

I am using a rich text editor on my website and i am using a label to display what the user entered last time he used the box, but when he submits the code it includes the html from the label. When I submit the form it writes the following....

```
<span id="bodyContent_header1"> <div style"float:right">The Text On The Page </div> </span>
```

I need to remove the `<span id="bodyContent_header1">   </span>`  from the code and keep the rest. Can anyone help? Also the code might include other span tags, so it should only remove this one each time.

Comment: Some code samples would definitely help.

Comment: I think you can do this with regex or by using string.split or .substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that such strings are a single line you can use the regex `^<span[^>]+>|</span>$` to replace the outermost `<span>` tags like this:

```
string strRegex = @"^<span[^>]+>|</span>$";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"<span id=""bodyContent_header1""> <div style""float:right"">The Text On The Page </div> </span>\n";
string strReplace = @"";
return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

This works on [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester).

Answer (score 1):

this regex select data from this tag

```
(?<=<span id="bodyContent_header1">)(.+)(</span>)
```

resolve this task with one regex replace imposible